# chrome tabs query property cannot be read when calling in Angular ngZone while in Incognito

Tags: angular, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a chrome extension using Angular.Everything is working ok, however, when you're in the incognito and run the chrome extension it throws an error on the console that the query property from `chrome.tabs` cannot be read. The below is the sample code.

```
sendMessage(action: string, data: any) {
    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true },
        (tabs) => this.zone.run(() => {
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {
                action: action,
                data: data
            });
        }));
}
```

As you can see, yes I encapsulated chrome tabs api in a service and run it using ngZone.

[image]

I'm calling the method inside `ngAfterViewInit`.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    // change iframe size based on this component content size
    this.chromeTabsService
        .sendMessageToContentScript(
            "change_iframe_height",
            this.documentRefService.getBodyOffsetHeight()
        );
}
```

**Manifest**

```
"background": {
    "scripts": ["scripts/background.js"]
},
"browser_action": {
    "default_title": "__MSG_browserActionTitle__",
    "default_icon": {
        "19": "assets/images/icon_19.png",
        "38": "assets/images/icon_38.png"
    }
},
"content_scripts": [{
    "all_frames": false,
    "js": ["scripts/contentscript.js"],
    "matches": [
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*"
    ],
    "run_at": "document_end"
}],
"web_accessible_resources": [
    "index.html",
    "assets/images/*"
],
"permissions": [
    "contextMenus",
    "management",
    "storage",
    "tabs",
    "<all_urls>"
]
```

Any suggestion on how to resolve this when you're in Incognito mode or is another api that I should call specifically when in Incognito mode?

Comment: Do you see this error in the popup's devtools console or the web page console? What's in [manifest's incognito key](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/incognito)? Did you explicitly enable the extension to run in incognito on chrome://extensions page?

Comment: @wOxxOm I have updated my question, I do not have any incognito key in the manifest.

Comment: @wOxxOm the error is in the popup's devtools console and yes I explicitly enabled incognito as I'm doing some testing.

Comment: Hmm, sounds like a bug then. Can you reproduce it after restarting the browser (quit + start)? Does it occur without devtools open?

Comment: @wOxxOm yes still happening I have tested it with different machine same problem. Yes it does even the devtools is not open. Do I have to add the incognito in the manifest?

Comment: @wOxxOm I added `"incognito": "split"` in the manifest and it is working now. thank you.